# Calculating Ka using Nernst Equation

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, equilibrium, analytical-chemistry, nernst-equation

I've heard multiple times that the Nernst Equation could be used to calculate K$_a$. How would one calculate the acidity constant, K$_a$, of a specific acid, using the Nernst Equation? The equilibrium itself is a proton transfer, not an electron one, so how would one use the equation in this case?